# Modding new style 'buttonless' touchpads

Tags: laptop, touchpad, input-device

I'm looking to buy a new laptop, and perhaps I'm old-fashioned, but I really hate these new button-less touchpads that seem to be on 90% of current machines. E.g.

[image]

My biggest peeve with these things is that the 'button' area itself (if the machine has a switch under the touchpad) is also touch sensitive, which means that I'm often moving the pointer by mistake as I go to click, missing what I wanted to click on.

**Short of sticking tape on the thing* are there any sort of software mods that you can do to stop the button area being touch sensitive?**

Actually a friend tried this on his, and it was *still* touch sensitive - perhaps it must be thick tape ;)

Comment: Oh, Why the -1?

Comment: Most likely because this question boils down to a software recommendation, which is off-topic according to the [FAQ]. Try simplifying the question to the cursor moving when you click, and not asking for a software-specific solution. Can you give an example of the touchpad? I'm familiar with the Apple Touchpads - you avoid this issue by simply not picking your finger up between the end of the movement and the click.

Comment: @DarthAndroid - IMO this isn't a shopping question - the only possibility I can see is software, but I don't know if it's even possible.  I'll add an example photo. I'm not looking for tips on how to move my finger, but thanks!

Comment: I'd say the question is fine as-is. There are some problems that can only be solved through software.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: Don't know what specific touchpad you would be using but on many of them you can enable tap to click so you only need to gently tap anywhere on the pad rather than pressing it down. This would be under Mouse setting in the Control Panel. Best to try out the laptop in a shop before buying it. Or consider buying a proper mouse.

Comment: @James: Yeah, I know about tap to click, but dont get on well with that and keep it dissabled - I'd like to use the mechanical switches under the touchpad (but the touch sensitivity of the buttons makes this difficult). Thanks

Comment: I believe you should be able to use one finger to move the pointer and at the same time use a different finger to press the button. If the touchpad driver is any good it should only move the pointer if the first finger moves. The only buttonless trackpad I have used is on a Macbook Pro in OS X and I'm pretty sure this works. Personally I much prefer to have normal buttons and/or use tap to click.

Comment: @James Ah that's interesting. On the Asus laptops I've tried it doesn't work like this (the second finger will nudge the mouse pointer). This gives me hope! I guess I need to try a few (I assumed they all worked like this).  If you put it as an answer I'll accept.